# Jquery: How do you use jquery selectors from a .get html?

Tags: jquery

I have been searching for awhile and haven't found an answer that has worked. I may have just mis-understood, so I apologise if this is a repeat question.

I have the code below and I can't 'convert' the $.get data to be able to be selected via jquery selectors so I can add/remove information before adding it to my page.

```
$.get('views/index.html').done(function (data){ 
   alert($(data).find('#elId').html());
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of data you're trying to pass?
I'm not very familiar yet of the type of format you're using in your get.
if you want, you can try this format.. this works the same:

```
$.ajax({
         url      : 'url name',
         method   : 'GET',
         dataType : 'type of data you are trying to GET', //text,json,html
         success  : function(data){
                   alert(data); //alert the whole data first
         }


})
```